# python - arrange an excel file with linked columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

There is an Excel file with more than 2000 rows, but it is like below:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 12 | AA | 22 |
| AA | 13 | AA | 23 |
| AA | 14 | AA | 24 |
| CC | 17 | DD | 1.4 |
| CC | 18 | DD | 1.2 |
| CC | 19 | DD | 13 |
| DD | 1.2 |  |  |
| DD | 1.1 |  |  |
| DD | 1.3 |  |  |

column A-B and C-D are linked. How I can to sort the column A and C and the rows in front of them place in the same row with the same order. The final Excel file should be like below:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 12 | AA | 22 |
| AA | 13 | AA | 23 |
| AA | 14 | AA | 24 |
| CC | 17 |  |  |
| CC | 18 |  |  |
| CC | 19 |  |  |
| DD | 1.2 | DD | 1.4 |
| DD | 1.1 | DD | 1.2 |
| DD | 1.3 | DD | 13 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you need by iterating through the complete set of groups defined by the values in columns A and C, and for each group you want to concatenate corresponding data frames from the left and right halves of your original dataset.

You can read in your data using pandas read_excel(), and after you sort it you can write it back out with DataFrame.to_excel().

To see how to sort your data, lets first make a toy dataset with different numbers of corresponding items in columns A and C (also allowing items to appear in either A or C but not both).

```
import pandas as pd
original_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([['AA', 12, 'AA', 22],
                                         ['AA', 13, 'DD', 1.4],
                                         ['CC', 17, 'DD', 1.5],
                                         ['DD', 1.3, '', '']],
                                        columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
original_df
```

---

```
    A     B   C    D
0  AA  12.0  AA   22
1  AA  13.0  DD  1.4
2  CC  17.0  DD  1.5
3  DD   1.3
```

Now we pull out the left and right halves of the data (columns A-B and C-D), make a list of all the groups identified by the values in columns A and C, juxtapose corresponding data frames from the left and right halves, and append them all together.

```
# Get left and right halves, dropping blanks.
left_df = original_df[['A', 'B']].query('A != ""')
right_df = original_df[['C', 'D']].query('C != ""')

# Build sorted list of unique values from original columns A and C.
groups = list(set(left_df.iloc[:,0]) | set(right_df.iloc[:,0]))
groups.sort()

# Assemble list of dataframes combining corresponding left-right data.
dfpairs = [pd.concat([left_df[left_df.A==g].reset_index(drop=True), 
                      right_df[right_df.C==g].reset_index(drop=True)],
                     axis='columns') for g in groups]

# Append all the dataframes together.
sorted_df = pd.concat(dfpairs, axis='index', ignore_index=True).fillna('')
sorted_df
```

---

```
    A    B   C    D
0  AA   12  AA   22
1  AA   13         
2  CC   17         
3  DD  1.3  DD  1.4
4           DD  1.5
```